# Phase (argument) of a complex top form

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, complex-manifolds

Let $\xi\in\Omega^{n,n}(X,\mathbb{C})$ be a volume form on a complex manifold $X$ of dimension $n$. For any other non vanishing top form $\eta\in\Omega^{n,n}(X,\mathbb{C}) $, there exists a function $f:X\to \mathbb{C}^*$ such that $\eta=f\xi$. We can associate to $\eta$ an "angle" $$\varphi_{\eta}:X\to S^1$$
defined as
$$f(z)=r(z)e^{i\varphi_{\eta}(z)}$$

Now I heard that this angle is well defined for any non vanishing volume form **even without fixing a base form $\xi$**.

Is that true? And if yes how is this defined?

Comment: Try taking $\xi=\eta$ and you get $f=1$, but if you take $\xi=i\eta$ you get $f=-i$, so I don't see how this can be independent of $\xi$.

Comment: But if $\xi$ is a real volume form, then it is defined up to real positive rescaling, so then the angle is defined clearly ok, and any two choices of $\xi$ give the same angle.